# Form didn't submit after ajax validation

Tags: jquery, ajax, validation

This question had been asked a lot of times, but I still confused where I made a mistake.
I need to validate form by ajax and submit it if everything is ok.
Here is my code:

```js
    $('#tl_form form').on('submit',function(e) {
        var $form = $(this);
        if($form.attr('validated')){
                        //Here the form should be send IMHO, but "return true" don't do it somehow:
                        console.log('ok'); // I can just see this 'ok' in console.
            return true;
        }
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            data: $form.serialize() + '&action=validate_tl_form',
            url: ajaxurl,
            success: function(data) {
                if (data.success) {
                    $form.attr('validated',true).submit();
                } else {
                                        console.log('error');
                }
            },
        });
        return false;
    });
```

Comment: You may need to prevent the default behavior first by using `e.preventDefault()` at the first line of the event then proceed to the logic.

Comment: You're using jquery submit (which then just recalls your handler), change to `$form.attr('validated',true)[0].submit();` to use vanilla submit.

Comment: Thanks for anwers,but not. `e.preventDefault()` did the same as `return fasle`.

Comment: `$form.attr('validated',true)[0].submit(); ` - is not a function.

Comment: @Movs  try these suggetions
1)Remove return false from the end of the function . 
2)add e.preventDefault() and e.stopPropagation() in else case of your if statement.
3) Unlikely but can you split the code of changing the validated attr value and submitting in two different lines.

Comment: I can't see what form data you are trying to validate or how you are validating it.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend to re-work your logic.

If you are submitting the entire form to the server *anyway* for validation, the server might as well simply accept it when it is valid, instead of sending "it is valid" to the client and expecting a form re-post.

You can show a validation hint on the client when the form was not valid.

```
$('#tl_form form').on('submit', function (e) {
    e.prenventDefault();
    $.post($(this).attr('action'), $(this).serialize()).done(function (data) {
        if (data.success) {
            // go to next step/page
        } else {
            // show validation hint
        }
    });
});
```

`e.prenventDefault();` prevents that the browser submits the form the regular way, since you're sending it via Ajax.

Comment: Yes. This is the decision. I made it that way.  But I still don't undestand why my code above don't work.

Comment: @Movs Not sure. When you see the `ok` in the console, this proves that the `validated` attribute was and `submit()` has been called. It *should* submit. Maybe there is another submit event handler somewhere else that prevents it.